# Draw TabControl like Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, look-and-feel

As part of manipulate (especially disabling) my TabControl I draw it myself!

Code:

```
InitializeComponent();

this.TabControl.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
this.TabControl.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(TabControlDrawItem);
this.TabControl.Selecting += new TabControlCancelEventHandler(TabControlSelecting);

...

private void TabControlDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    TabPage page = m_tcView.TabPages[e.Index];
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(page.BackColor), e.Bounds);            

    Rectangle paddedBounds = e.Bounds;
    int yOffset = (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected) ? -2 : 1;
    paddedBounds.Offset(1, yOffset);

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, page.Text, this.Font, paddedBounds, page.ForeColor);
}

private void TabControlSelecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.TabPage.Enabled == false)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

But I'm not satisfied with the look and feel! I want it similar to the VS2012 generated TabControl (see picture)! Which changes are needed?

[image: VS2012 generated TabControl]

Thx

Comment: do you mean docking windows? or what exactly do you need?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your result compared with the stock TabControl?

Comment: Actually...I think your code is doing little.  If you really want that kind of control, you should create a new class and inherit from `TabControl`.  Then you can use `overrides` to fully control what is drawn and how it looks and works.